# One method, multiple list types

Tags: c#

I'd like to write one method to accomplish a task rather than many. I would be passing lists whose types could be one of several custom classes. Is that possible? A sample to explain what I am after with "??" marking where I don't know how the syntax might work follows. Thank you.

```
private static void MoveSuccessRecords(List<??> thisList, string VUEFileName, string folderArchive, string folderError)
{
    StreamWriter successWriter = new StreamWriter(folderArchive + VUEFileName.Replace(extension, "_COMPLETE" + extension), true);
    CsvWriter successCSV = new CsvWriter(successWriter);

    successCSV.WriteHeader<??>();

    foreach (var item in thisList)
    {
        successCSV.WriteRecord(item);
    }

    successCSV.Dispose();
    successWriter.Dispose();
    successWriter.Close();
}
```

Comment: Do these classes implement a common interface? Do you have the possibility to do so?

Comment: Does `WriteRecord` have a overload that takes in a `object` type? If not please tell us what types it does as all the current answers that specify using `T` will not work if it does not accept `object`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make this method a generic method, in the same way that List is a generic class.  You can reuse the generic parameter when giving the parameter for List:

```
private static void MoveSuccessRecords<T>(List<T> thisList, string VUEFileName, string folderArchive, string folderError)
{
    StreamWriter successWriter = new StreamWriter(folderArchive + VUEFileName.Replace(extension, "_COMPLETE" + extension), true);
    CsvWriter successCSV = new CsvWriter(successWriter);

    successCSV.WriteHeader<T>();

    foreach (var item in thisList)
    {
        successCSV.WriteRecord(item);
    }

    successCSV.Dispose();
    successWriter.Dispose();
    successWriter.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping this .NET and C# rookie who knew what he wanted but not how to vocalize it in the proper terminology.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking to make the method generic. In which case you merely need to adapt the method signature so that it accepts a type argument `T`

```
static void MoveSuccessRecords<T>(List<T> thisList, string ..)
```

You can then choose to be explicit about the type argument or let the compiler deduce the generic type argument from the given argument

```
var someList = new List<string>();
MoveSuccessRecords<string>(someList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, without knowing all the details or pondering it too much, here is what I would do:

1) Use List to define thisList
2) Use item.GetType() to determine the type of item in the list (you indicated that while the objects might be similar, they might not be the same).  An Interface would make this easier - but I didn't see a response to that comment.  Then you can pass the appropriate item to the WriteRecord method.

Hope you get the answer you are looking for.